# Redux action creators with nested closures

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, redux-thunk, currying

Is there a way one could return multiple nested closures in an action creator in Redux?

Consider a `log` action creator that instead of accepting `log(topic, level, message)`, can be written as 4 nested functions, each accepting only one scope of the whole parameters like `topic => level => message => (dispatch, getState)`?

### Straight forward:

```
function log(topic, level, message) {
  return {type: 'LOG', topic, level, message };
}
```

### Nested:

```
function log(topic) {
  return function(level) {
    return function(message) {
      return function(dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOG', topic, level, message });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Redux-thunk

I know that **redux-thunk** is using a similar pattern leveraging Redux middleware system to provide async action creators, but can't make it work with the pattern I desire.

Answer (score 0):

With plain redux, all actions functions must return a simple JavaScript object. Middleware such as `thunk` allows you to return functions which the thunk middle ware will resolve to a final JavaScript object for redux to process. The pattern I have seen is that the function returns a function which takes a single parameter, the `dispatch`:

```
function log(topic, level, message, getState) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch(function(dispatch) {
      dispatch (function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOG', topic, level, message });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Note this is not tested. Hopefully this gives you the general idea.

Comment: This gave me the idea of multiple dispatchs which is nice, but still doesn't solve the actual issue. Is it possible for log to break into multiple single argument functions? Similar to partial applications?

Comment: @FarzadYZ Not that I am aware of. I don't know how you would pass in the arguments to the other functions?

Comment: The problem is indeed the parameters passed to middle functions. Maybe it's not just doable.